# jsp страница и кодировка UTF-8

Tags: jsp, utf-8, spring-mvc

При отправление POST запроса c jsp страницы в контроллер, данные, которые введены на русском или украинском отображаются как ÐÐ½Ð´ÑÐµÐ¹

Я уже пересмотрел все варианты решения проблемы, но ничего не помогает. Изначально думал, что это проблема в БД, но нет.

Сделал все, как было написано на страницах интернета:

1. по скольку, использую томкат, то прописал кодировку URI

   ```
   <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
       useBodyEncodingForURI="UTF-8" />
   ```
2. кодировку страницы:  `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`
3. Мета тег: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`
4. в конфиг. классе добавил:

   ```
   private static final String VIEW_RESOLVER_CONTENT_TYPE = "text/html;charset=UTF-8";
   viewResolver.setContentType(VIEW_RESOLVER_CONTENT_TYPE);`
   ```
5. По скольку конфигурация задается программно, добавил web.xml и там прописал конфигурацию jsp

   ```
   <web-app
       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"  version="3.0">
   <jsp-config>        <jsp-property-group>
           <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
           <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>        </jsp-property-group>
   </jsp-config>
   ```

   `

Но ничего из того что я сделал, мне не помогло.

Comment: request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value = "/user/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String createNewUser(
   @Valid @ModelAttribute("user") RegistrationForm userAccountData,
   BindingResult result, WebRequest request)
   throws DuplicateEmailException {
 }`

Как правильно это прописать в моем методе ? 
Или лучше это сделать в интерцепторе ?

Answer (score 1):

нужно указать кодировку на входе:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");   

<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```